# Why is NoResultException a system exception?

Tags: java, rest, jpa, ejb

Why did the EJB powers that be decide that `NoResultException` resulting from JPA's `getSingleResult()` method should be a system exception rather than a typical application exception?

The method `getSingleResult()` could have been used for a wide variety of cases, but it instead has been made into one that is a pain to work with in 99% of cases: instead of allowing this exception to bubble, I now have to catch it everywhere and either return null or throw my own custom application exception, since an equivalent application exception does not exist by default. This design seems severely inconsiderate to everyday use, and also swallows up a perfectly good exception name that I could have used instead.

What scenarios would having `NoResultException` as a system exception even represent? The assumption that a resource not existing is a system-wide problem seems antithetical to RESTful design.

Comment: I agree. Much of the code I have worked with/reviewed that interacts with JPA directly forgoes the use of `getSingleResult()` in favor of `getResultList()`, with boilerplate that returns null if the list is empty etc. Actually, a lot of that legacy code I used to see is now being replaced in favor of Spring Data JPA et al. However - specifically - I believe the motivation was that "the caller expects exactly one result back and, since `PersistenceException`s invalidate the `EntityManager` state (e.g. the Hibernate `Session`), if she doesn't get exactly one back, I will assume invalid state".

Comment: * This may explain why it can throw `NoResultException` as well as `NonUniqueResultException`.

Comment: *FYI:* There is no such thing as a *system* exception or an *application* exception. There are *checked* and *unchecked* exceptions, but the "system" come with both kinds, and your application can also have custom exceptions of both kinds.

Comment: *"also swallows up a perfectly good exception name that I could have used"* There is nothing preventing you from creating an *unchecked* exception named `NoResultException`. Classes names don't have to be unique, as long as they are in different packages, exactly like file names don't have to be unique, as long as they are in different folders.

Comment: I feel that reusing the name could be confusing to anyone reading the code with a fresh set of eyes, and also could allow for some user error when writing code meant to use the custom exception. The system vs. application exception is thing an EJB distinction and not a pure java thing: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbpj/index.html